# Epsilon-Delta Proof at infinity

Tags: limits, infinity

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<y<1$. Let also be $f(y)=y^n$ and $g(y)=y^{n+1}$.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{f(y)}{g(y)} = L $$

What is the value of $L$ using the epsilon-delta definition of limit?

---

Edit

Consider $n \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is n natural number? If so, then do you mean the limit in discrete sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $n$,

$$
\frac{f(y)}{g(y)} = \frac{y^n}{y^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{y}
$$

Now fix $\epsilon > 0$.  Choose $N = 1$.
For $n > N$, we have
$$
\left|
\frac{f_{(n)}(y)}{g_{(n)}(y)} - \frac{1}{y}
\right|
=
\left|
\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y} 
\right|
= 0 < \epsilon.
$$
Q. E. D.

Comment: This is the answer that I arrived. The problem is that I can also choose $N=0$ and the answer holds. But as far as I could understand $\delta$ must be $\delta > 0$.

Comment: @EriveltonGeraldoNepomuceno Perhaps the reason you are confused is that in this kind of "$\epsilon$-$\delta$" proof (one with the limit as $n \to \infty$), there is no $\delta$ at all.  Instead there is $N$.  And $N$ can be any natural number.  Also, in a normal $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, you can choose $\delta$ to be any real number $> 0$.

Comment: I see. But $N$ must be also $N>0$. Take a look at   
Take a look at http://www.whfreeman.com/Catalog/static/whf/taalmankohnpreview/images/c01Limits_TK.pdf page 94.

Comment: @EriveltonGeraldoNepomuceno It doesn't matter, actually.  You can find $N > 0$, $N \ge 0$, or $N > 1000$ for all the difference it will make.

Answer (score 0):

For $0<y<1$, it must be $L=1/y$

Comment: Is that obvious irrespective of n? If n is a real number, what happens?

Comment: The post explicitly says $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: True! I am asking if n is not a natural number. If we consider it irrational or rational, what happens?

Comment: I changed the post. I think that is my concern. For me it does not make sense to give a limit irrespective of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

As $\frac{f(y)}{g(y)} = \frac{1}{y}$ and does not depend on $n$, then this limit equals exactly $\frac{1}{y}$.

Using the epsilon-delta definition of limit you can write $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists n_0 = 1: \forall n > n_0 \; \left|\frac{f(y)}{g(y)} - \frac{1}{y}\right| < \varepsilon$, because $\left|\frac{f(y)}{g(y)} - \frac{1}{y}\right| = 0$ and does not depend on $n$.

Comment: I got your point, but I have two functions. I can see those functions as two different systems that have as input $y$ and $n$. First I have to calculate the values of each function. Observe that I should also have $\lim_{n \to \infty}=\frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y)}{\lim_{n \to \infty} g(y)}$. If I simply cut down $n$ I do not take into account that it goes to infinity!